# Why can't I echo a simple Zend form?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-form

I've set up a simple form in my controller:

```
$form = new Zend_Form;
$form->addElement(new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name'));
$this->view->form = $form;
```

However when I go to echo it in my view:

```
echo $this->form;
```

I get `Catchable fatal error: Method Zend_Form::__toString() must return a string value in myView.phtml`.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: it's not this code, copied and pasted to an action/view works great. Did you change something somewhere else or mess with encoding somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the decorator

```
$form->setDecorators( array( array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => '_forms/simple.phtml'))));
```

Comment: The Zend_Form constructor automatically calls `loadDefaultDecorators()`